# WebView example android

Tags: android, android-webview

There is a error in mView, I need solution

```
package com.example.account;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class WebView extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}

}
```

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Cannot cast from view to webview

```
WebView mView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: define `doesn't it work?`

Comment: Cannot cast from view to webview 

    WebView mView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1)

Comment: @user3422485 please upload full code of your webview file.

Comment: Just check it out this tutorial link [Android WebView Example](https://androidride.com/android-webview-example-tutorial-kotlin-java-download-source-code/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your activity name as `WebView`. This name is already used by SDK API. This is the reason it is giving you error.

To solve it, just rename your `WebView.java` file to some another name like `MyWebView.java` then your problem will surely solve.

To safely rename your .java file, Just go to packageexplorer , select WebView.java and press <kbd>F2</kbd>, and give new name.

Comment: thanks .but interesting while during compile java doesn't say that there is a problem in name

Comment: @user3422485, yes, it doesnt give error at compilation time, It only gives such error at run time.

Comment: thank you), but if you want to create a class Class,the compiler say there is a problem)

Comment: @user3422485 I hope this feature will be there in future.

Answer (score 3):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

give me feedback on this.

**Update:**
You should change your Activity name with Different one. or defined your `WebView` with different name like:

```
WebView mView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1)
```

Comment: Agree with you but see this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/). I think OP is using it.

Comment: there is same problem,after save all clean project,(Cannot cast from view to webview)

Comment: @user3422485 , can you upload the full code, please ?

Comment: @user3422485 error is generated for some different reason.plz post your code

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may help

**1** . Using Eclipse, create a new Android project and name it as WebView.

**2** . Add the following statements to the main.xml file:

```
<?xml​ version=”1.0” ​encoding=”utf-8”?>
<LinearLayout ​xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android” ​​​​android:orientation=”vertical” ​​​​
android:layout_width=”fill_parent” ​
​​​android:layout_height=”fill_parent” ​​​​>

<WebView
android:id=”@+id/webview1” ​​
​​android:layout_width=”wrap_content” ​
​​​android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />

</LinearLayout>
```

**3** . In the MainActivity.java file, add the following statements in bold:

```
package​ com.emergingandroidtech.WebView;
import​ android.app.Activity;
import ​android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public ​class ​MainActivity​ extends​ Activity
​{
​​​​
/**​Called​ when​ the ​activity ​is ​first ​created.​*/

​@Override ​​
​​public ​void ​onCreate(Bundle​savedInstanceState)​
{
​​​​​​​​super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
​setContentView(R.layout.main);
​​​​​​​​
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
​​​​​​​​WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings(); ​​
​​​​​​webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
​​​​​​​​wv.loadUrl( ​​​​​​​​“www.google.com”);
​​​​}
}
```

**4**. Don't forget to give the internet permission in manifest file

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should keep webview inside any parent view

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android WebView Example]

- **Do not use reserved words as your variable, class and method name.**
- Here, **WebView** is reserved or already used by SDK. If you use that word again, Compiler will get confused.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
//loads androidride homepage to webview
webview.loadUrl("https://www.androidride.com");
}
}
```